# What is the fastest text rendering method in a command prompt when using C++

Tags: c++, command-prompt, cout

ATM I'm working on a game so I'm looking for a method to render an entire area of chars in' a blink of an eye. Now I'm having trouble with slow rendering speeds (or rather printing speeds to be specific here and I know cout a slow method but that was like the first option I'm using now)

So is there some way of displaying text fast enough so I won't have trouble with characters flickering or simply characters being drawn one after another because I'm using loops to draw them.

Any advice is apreciated

edit: even when everyone is downvoting this like hell I think this is a decent question that is useful for beginning programmers. Instead of endless hours of scouting the internet I now have an actual idea of how I should tackle this issue

Comment: OS you want to support? Things you have already tried? Actual numbers (is it feasible)?

Comment: Use `ncurses` or `pdcurses`. Writes first go into an internal buffer, and only the relevant portion of the screen is actually updated when you call `refresh()`. The C++ standard I/O library is very limited in this regard.

Comment: Well I tried printing a block of characters by using cout and a loop but I know there are faster methods to do so but as you can tell I'm not that experienced to know what to use

Comment: Very likely, the majority of time used is the "shuffle pixels around on the display". Try using "full-screen mode" (on Linux, use `CTRL-ALT-F3`, ALT-ENTER in DOS). Mind you, on my machine, the XTerm is faster - by a factor of 7.

Comment: Thanks @DanielKamilKozar. I found some information here http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/ about how to program with ncurses. This was exactly what I was looking for. I'll research this for a bit and see if I get to something playable :)

Comment: @MatsPetersson it is indeed faster but the loop still takes to long to finish when I cout a block of characters (width:70 height:40)

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar You might want to promote your comment to an answer.  :)

Comment: What is "too long" in this case? What platform? What compiler?

Comment: @MatsPetersson GNU GCC compiler, windows xp, and by "too long" I mean it doesn't appear in a fraction of a second.

Comment: Ok, I just tried on my Linux machine, and it takes 0.006s-0.018s to print 40 lines of 70 characters. Will report back with times for Visual Studio. I don't have gcc on my windows machine.

Comment: @JensAckou: I have just added some code to my answer, showing that printf is a lot faster (but still a lot slower than my linux machine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ standard input/output library is very limited when it comes to the operations that can be done in regards to the traditional terminal support.

Your only way out of this is to use a specialized library. As I mentioned in my comment, `ncurses` or `pdcurses` should suffice, depending on the platform you're on.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick comparison shows that `cout` in Visual Studio is a lot slower than `printf` (noticeable difference) - I will return with an edit of exactly how big a difference.

Obviously, a library for UI operations is likely to be much better, as it has the ability to move cursor around, and only redraw bits of the screen that actually changed, etc.

Edit: I used the following code to measure the speed of the two output methods:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

int main(int argc, char **)
{
    clock_t t = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        if (argc == 1)
        {
            std::cout << "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n";
        }
        else
        {
            printf("0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n");
        }
    }
    std::cout.flush();
    t = clock()-t;
    std::cout << "Time = " << std::setprecision(3) << t / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, it takes approximately 0.1s (0.098-0.113s) with `printf` ('mytest x') and around 0.8s (0.776-0.860) with the `cout` ('mytest').